# scp with tar pipe and continue proceeding if shell is closed

Tags: ssh, tar

I am trying to send my files to another server with this command:

```
    tar zcvf - /var/www/html | ssh root@x.x.x.x "cat > /backup.tar.gz"
```

And I want to send it to background with this commands "ctrl+z" and "bg" and "disown"
but when I execute "bg" It continues showing me list of files that are being processed and does not let me to run "disown".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and just put this into a [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) session and afterwards, disconnect from it.  This is a much better approach then the old backgrounding/`nohup`ing way, IMHO.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand. what is screen session? (I am using ssh to connect my server)

Comment: After a little googling now I know what you meant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the other answer - take a look at `nohup` - which lets you redirect output to a log file, and tells your process to ignore 'HANGUP' kill signals.

Comment: nohup does not work when command prompts for password

Comment: Good point. I had assumed ssh public-private key authentication.